# Как получить значения по совпадению?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть у меня записи:
car_id user_id created_at count
26 1 - -
27 1 - -
27 8 - -

Мне нужно достать пользователей у которых одинаковый car_id зная только user_id. Как это можно сделать?
потому что пишу user_id IN (1, 8) выводит 3 записи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю без джойна можно обойтись, но пока в голову ничего не приходит.

```
SELECT tb1.car_id FROM `cars` as tb1 
left join `cars` as tb2 on tb2.car_id = tb1.car_id and tb2.user_id != tb1.user_id
WHERE tb1.user_id in (1,8) and tb2.user_id is not null 
group by tb1.car_id
```

Comment: мне в итоге нужно получить 
27 1 - -
27 8 - -

Запрос отрабатывает не правильно.

Comment: @Fitstd "Мне нужно достать пользователей у которых одинаковый car_id зная только user_id" этот запрос будет работать если вы знаете хотя бы одного пользователя, и соответственно можете получить, у кого такая же машина

Comment: я знаю пользователя с id = 1 и с id = 8. Мне нужно получить машину которая есть и в 1 и у 8

Comment: @Fitstd обновил, второй запрос твой)

Comment: Спасибо за время уделенное. Но все же, почему сюда попадает car_id = 26? Ведь нужно только 27, потому что она есть в 1 и у 8

Comment: @Fitstd проверь сейчас

Comment: @Fitstd проверь, если что то придумаю, скину получше вариант

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct a1.user_id from Cars a1
join Cars a2 on
a1.car_id = a2.car_id
and a1.user_id != a2.user_id
where a1.car_id in (
select car_id from cars 
where user_id in (....))
```

Переделал немного условие, вроде возвращает именно то, что нужно автору.

Comment: мой вариант без подзапроса